# How many slokas are there in the Bhavarthadipika?

Tags: mahabharata, critical-edition

According to BORI (the Bhandarkar Oriental Research Institute), how many slokas are there in the Bhavarthadipika? (And therefore, how many  slokas are there in Nilakantha Chaturdhar's commentary on the Mahabharata?)